# Heroku Scheduler timeout

Tags: heroku, scheduler

I'm using the Heroku Scheduler to launch a script which can take up to 5-10min to complete.

Is it a problem? Because my script don't seem to finish properly...apparently it hangs up after a while.

As my script is running only once a day I was thinking it should be ok.

Thanks for help!

Comment: I'm now running the script inside a worker and it's working just fine!